# Upgrade Go dependency module to a new major version

Tags: go, module, upgrade

How to update/upgrade Go dependency module to a new major version?

- I tried `go get -v -u github.com/gofiber/fiber` but that only get it upgraded to `v1.14.6`, not the `v2.0.1` as seen on its git page.
- I tried `go get -v -u github.com/gofiber/fiber@v2.0.1`, but get the following errors:

`go get github.com/gofiber/fiber@v2.0.1: github.com/gofiber/fiber@v2.0.1: invalid version: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v2`

- I then tried `go get -v -u github.com/gofiber/fiber@v2`, but get the following errors: `go get github.com/gofiber/fiber@v2: no matching versions for query "v2"`

I then did some research, some are not detailed enough and miss the important info:

- https://golang.cafe/blog/upgrade-dependencies-golang.html

Some are just too wordy, talking a bunch of broad topics and not specific on the updating Go dependency module to a new major version task:

- https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2020/03/25/working-with-go-modules-versioning/

So I'm thinking a *concise* and *complete* list of what things need to be done for updating Go dependency module to a new major version would be beneficial to the Go community as a whole.

Comment: Import `github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2` instead of `github.com/gofiber/fiber`.

Comment: I meant to have stressed *complete* list as well, @Peter, as I'm thinking that's not the only thing I need to do...

Comment: Here's a tool which automates upgrading major versions: https://github.com/icholy/gomajor

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler than I thought --

- replace every import of `github.com/gofiber/fiber` with `github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2`
- do `go get -v ./...`

That's it. Not sure if it is a complete list thought, but it works for my specific case.

The rest is just to fix whatever the API changes that the new major version requires.